# Usar condições dentro de um prepare() mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho uma query com algumas condições, não é sempre que ela ocorre

```
$query="SELECT FA_NUMBER FROM FAMILIA";

if(!empty($FA_NUMBER )){
 $query .= 'WHERE FA_NUMBER = ?;
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $fo_number);
$stmt->execute();
```

O problema é, nem sempre eu vou ter parâmetros preenchidos, só quando entra na condição, como eu defino o bind_param de acordo com as várias condições da minha função se ela trabalha por ordem e deve ser preenchida?

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa repetir o `if`:

```
$query = "SELECT FA_NUMBER FROM FAMILIA";
if (!empty($FA_NUMBER)) {
  $query .= 'WHERE FA_NUMBER = ?';
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
if (!empty($FA_NUMBER)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $fo_number);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Feio, mas resolve. Outra organização possível, um pouco mais repetitiva, talvez mais legível:

```
if (!empty($FA_NUMBER)) {
  $query = 'SELECT FA_NUMBER FROM FAMILIA WHERE FA_NUMBER = ?';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $fo_number);
} else {
  $query = "SELECT FA_NUMBER FROM FAMILIA";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
}
$stmt->execute();
```